# import может быть использован только в модуле. А почему?

Tags: javascript, импорт, модули

К странице подключены 2 скрипта:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="DOMOperations.js" type="module"></script>
```

`DOMOperations` является модулем, предоставляющим какие-то обертки над DOM операциями:

```
// DOMOperations.js

export function printToBody(str) {
    let textNode = document.createTextNode(str);
    document.body.appendChild(textNode);
}
```

`script` является главным скриптом, который импортирует некоторый функционал, предоставляемый модулем:

```
// script.js

import {printToBody} from "./DOMOperations.js";

printToBody("Hello!");
```

Но при таком подключении скриптов ничего не работает, потому что, как говорит FireFox, `import` выражения могут быть только в верхнем уровне **модуля**:

> SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

ОК, укажем, что главный скрипт - это модуль:

```
<script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="DOMOperations.js"></script>
```

Но теперь, даже несмотря на то, что все, вроде бы, работает, в консоли все равно есть ошибка, правда уже другая:

> SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module

То есть еще и `export` выражения могут быть только в верхнем уровне модуля. Выходит, надо оба файла подключить как модули?

```
<script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="DOMOperations.js" type="module"></script>
```

Так тоже все работает, и ошибок никаких нет. Но возникает вполне закономерный вопрос: **а где логика?**

Почему `import` выражения могут появляться только в **модуле**? Ведь куда более вероятно, что я захочу *импортировать* какой-то функционал, *предоставляемый* модулем, то есть *из* модуля, а не наоборот.

Я бы подумал, что так происходит из за того, что реализация модулей находится еще в ранней стадии (более того, доступна только при определенных настройках браузера), но даже те немногие примеры, что мне удалось найти в интернете, тоже [используют](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/) такой подход:

```
<script type="module">
  import {addTextToBody} from './utils.js'; // импорты в модуле!

  addTextToBody('Modules are pretty cool.');
</script>
```

Прошу объяснить, почему это реализовано именно так.

Comment: [немного спецификаций](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#integration-with-the-javascript-module-system)

Comment: @Grundy не совсем понятно, в каком месте по приведенной ссылке дается ответ на мой вопрос. Не могли бы вы привести цитату (или хотя бы ее часть, чтобы я мог найти на странице)?

Comment: @Grundy я тут перечитал инфу по вашей ссылке. Скажите, я правильно понимаю, что вы говорили о вот этой вот части: "how the module system is bootstrapped, via the script element with type attribute set to "module" и о следующей за ней Note'е?

Comment: Наверное о ней :-)

Comment: @Grundy а нет ли случайно где-то более подробной информации по поводу того, почему именно слово "module" используется в этих целях? Почему не, например, что-то вроде "has-modules" или "module-loader"? Почему именно такое сбивающее с толку слово? Просто может натыкались уже, так чтоб я знал, есть ли смысл искать вообще.

Comment: Не обращал внимания раньше